# Protractor running tests in sequence with different logins

Tags: selenium, protractor, ui-automation

I am using Protractor to create automated tests for our Angular project. To run tests I enter the command `npm run e2e`. Therefore I need tests to run in sequence in `app.e2e.spec.ts`. But my challange is that I need to test different user role logins to system. To be able to achieve this, I tried

```
describe('project service account', () => { 
 it('should login with service account')
});
describe('project admin account', () => { 
 it('should login with admin account')
});
```

But when I run these tests, It only executes the first `describe()`. Do you have any suggestions how can I run multiple tests in different `describe()`s

Edit:  Added error messages

````
*                    Failures                    *
**************************************************

1) workspace-project service account  App should logout when logout button clicked
  - Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="mainLoginButton"]"}
    (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

2) workspace-project admin account App should login with admin account
  - Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="mainLoginUser"]"}
    (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

3) workspace-project admin account App should logout when logout button clicked
  - Failed: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"*[id="mainLoginButton"]"}
    (Session info: chrome=78.0.3904.97)
    (Driver info: chromedriver=78.0.3904.105 (60e2d8774a8151efa6a00b1f358371b1e0e07ee2-refs/branch-heads/3904@{#877}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.18362 x86_64)

Executed 28 of 28 specs (3 FAILED) in 52 secs.
[10:02:23] I/launcher - 0 instance(s) of WebDriver still running
[10:02:23] I/launcher - chrome #01 failed 3 test(s)
[10:02:23] I/launcher - overall: 3 failed spec(s)
[10:02:23] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! eos@2.0.0-PL-DEV e2e: `ng e2e`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the eos@2.0.0-PL-DEV e2e script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-19T07_02_24_084Z-debug.log```
````

Comment: Executing only one describe block of two is not expected behaviour. So the actual issue is not how can you run multiple tests in different describe blocks but WHY it's not running second describe block. No sure where the issue is but try to add the console output to your question (the console output you get after executing your tests)

Comment: @YuriyGerasimovich  I added terminal output, but the error is not about not running two test one after another. It is an error of locating an xpath, however xpath is correct and when I run tests seperately, they are running individually

Comment: In the question you have mentioned that 'It only executes the first describe()' but in the output it shows that both 'service account' and 'project admin' blocks are executing (even if it fails it anyway). Can you please describe once again what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @YuriyGerasimovich Thank you for your help and guiding. After your advises and researches I figured out how to implement multiple user role tests. I will use one "describe" and "it()" methods will have different user role tests.